# How to using other Jquery template tags inside {{tmpl}} tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I was not able to call any other template tag inside `{{tmpl}}`. Looks like the parser is failing to identify other tags which are passed to `{{tmpl}}` tag.

For Example :

```
{{tmpl(Students) '<span>${$data.Name}</span>'}}
```

can somebody let me know if above example is legal?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is

```
{{tmpl( [data], [options] ) template}} content {{/tmpl}}
```

where `template` is the `The HTML markup or text to use as a template.` which means you most likely won't be able to do that. I don't know if it matters but you could try to use double quotes like you see in the examples, because single quotes are known for not evaluating embedded variables...